# PHP Object Oriented - Real Case

Tags: php, oop

I have a new project (e-commerce website) and I decided to try OOP as my new programming skill. I read few books and start understanding what class, method, etc used for. but, unfortunately none of these book I read give me a clue what or which part of the project should I treated as an object.

for example, I know that users, products, vendors are objects and it should have its own class.

but what about shopping cart, menus, warehouse, user comments / review? are these objects too?

if there's a book or references out there for this with real case, not using car, bird and hat as an example, please let me know. thank you so much.

Comment: You can use classes for whatever you want to, you're the designer.

Comment: shopping cart, menus, warehouse, user comments / review are all good candidates for their own objects since they are standard structures that you will want to access and use in different parts of your application.

Comment: My suggestion will be you should try opencart / prestashop / woocommerce  notice how each of these works . Than you can have a better imagination of what you want to do and how .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each database table should be an object. For example you are building application where you save notes. For this application, first of all you need table for notes, which will be main table and have Foreign Keys referring to other table ID-s, such as "Type", "User", "Status" and anything that's related to "Note". So you create database with tables.

```
Note -> Id, Title, Description, Type(Foreign Key), Status(Foreign Key), User(Foreign Key).

Type -> Id, TypeName.

Status -> Id, StatusName.

User -> Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Role
```

After having experience in some other frameworks I found out that first of all you should create Administrator panel for your application and start with basic CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations as it will help you build some kind of rudimentary functionality that you may use for other parts of application.

And here we go:

```
class Note
{
    private $id, $title, $description, $type, $status, $user;
    private $conObj;

    public Note()
    {

    }
}

class Type 
{
    private $id, $typeName, $conObj;

    public Type()
    {
    }
}

class Status
{
    private $id, $statusName, $conObj;

    public Status()
    {
    }
}

class User
{
    private $id, $firstName, $lastName, $email, $role, $conObj;

    public User()
    {
    }
}
```

Each class can have functions like insert, update, selectAll, selectUnique. 
So you also create connection class.

```
class Connection
{
    private $hostName, $userName, $password, $dbName;
    private $conObj;

    public Connection()
    {

    }

    public Connect()
    {
        $this->conObj = new mysqli($this->hostName, $this->userName, $this->password, $this->dbName)
    } 


}
```

After that, it's up to you to decide how connect "Connection" class instances to other class instances.

Comment: wow... that's exactly what I want to read from this forum, DDeme. I really appreciate it a lot. thank you for this crystal clear information! I LIKE IT!!! ;-)

Comment: @RobertHanson thanks for feedback, also don't forget to check my post and help me to gain points :D

Comment: marked as an answer, DDeme.... thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

The tricky part about OOP is that there is no one way to do it. Just like building a house, you may choose any type of architecture you like. What is an object depends on what you're building and how flexible you want each part to be. When you're building a project, you must decide which parts are to be focused. Then they get to be the objects (i.e the main domain of your application).

Sometimes the objects can get big, and they need to be separated into another class and instead communicate with each other. One thing about software development is that you learn as you go, by making mistakes along the way. And that is how you learn actually to identify the pitfalls of design decisions. Too much of upfront design decision isn't that effective either, but too less can harm a lot too, if you know that the project is going to last a while. It all depends on how big a project is going to be.

I say go ahead and try coding already! You will be surprised how much you learn as you code and refactor your own code. And don't forget to ask more questions as you go along. Have fun!